# MySQL query syntax when data to update query from select (many rows)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna to update `test1` table, and i get data from `test2` table. I'm trying to use JOIN but it isn't working.

My query:

```
UPDATE `test1` INNER JOIN `test2` ON `test2`.`where`=`test1`.`id` SET `test1`.`value`=`test1`.`value`+`test2`.`add`
```

I have two records in `test2` and one record in `test1`.

Test1:

```
id => 1
value => 0
```

Test2:

```
id => 1
where => 1
add => 1

id => 2
where => 1
add => 2
```

Result of this query is `test1`.`value`=1, not 3. This is possible in SQL?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but your 'where' statement must be at the end of your query. Update (something) -> Set (something) -> Where (something), instead of the followed order you did.

Comment: NewGuy, why do you expect it to be 3? The only record of `test1` is joined with the first record of `test2`, and `test1.value` is set to 0 + 1. Dorvalla, `where` is a name of a column. :)

Comment: Try writing it the way I showed below. I think how you are setting up the query is confusing. You are showing your where as a column on test2.where.

Comment: Olexa, i'm bad in SQL, yeah, it's fact, one record from test1 and test2, i'm so stupid :( But i wanna to have 3 at the end. Shredder solution is working, i expected this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on a sub-query that gets the sum of the `add` column grouped by the `where` column. Try this

```
UPDATE `test1` t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `where`, SUM(`add`) as `add` FROM test2 GROUP BY `where`
) as t2
ON t1.id = t2.`where`
SET t1.`value` = t2.`add`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e07e/1

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test1 
SET test1.value = test1.value + test2.add
FROM test1 INNER JOIN test2 ON (test1.ID = test2.ID)
GO
```

I believe this is what you are trying to do.